# A difference between Seed and Rand.Seed

Tags: go, random

The golang docs says that

> Seed, unlike the Rand.Seed method, is safe for concurrent use.

The `rand.Seed` is actually from `math/rand` package, but what is Seed? If `Seed` is another function then it's not present in `math/rand` so it's unclear from where that function comes from?

*update:*
I'm exploring the demo program where in `main` we execute

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
go process(...)
go process(...)
```

where the `process` is determined like

```
func process(...) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(30)) * time.Second)
    ...
}
```

We are using the same seed in two different threads, so is such using of `rand.Seed` considered to be a thread non-safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [`rand.Seed()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed) *function*, and there is a [`Rand.Seed()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand.Seed) *method*. Your quote originates from the documentation of the `Rand.Seed()` method.

Global functions of the [`math/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/) package operate on a global [`rand.Rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand) instance. If you check the source code of `rand.Seed()`:

```
func Seed(seed int64) { globalRand.Seed(seed) }
```

The global functions are safe for concurrent use, so all other packages can use it (in a shared manner). The global `rand.Rand` instance is provided for convenience, you can use it "out-of-the box" without any preparation (except the need to properly seed it) and without any synchronization.

Instances of `rand.Rand` are not safe for concurrent use, each goroutine that needs a `rand.Rand` for deterministic random sequences should create one, and seed it appropriately. Or if a `rand.Rand` is to be shared between multiple goroutines, explicit synchronization is required.

Pros of using the global `rand.Rand` (via the global functions) are: (1) ease of use (it's implicitly shared with everyone) and (2) no synchronization is needed.

Pros of creating and using a custom `rand.Rand` instance: (1) it's faster (it's not synchronized implicitly) and (2) you are in control of who has access to it, so you can use it to repeat pseudo-random sequences (you can't do that with the global instance as "anyone" may use it concurrently with you).

**Edit:**

> We are using the same seed in two different threads, so is such using of `rand.Seed` considered to be a thread non-safe?

You only call `rand.Seed` once, so actually it doesn't even matter if it's thread safe or not, it is not called concurrently. If `rand.Seed()` would be called from multiple goroutines concurrently, only then would it matter whether it's safe for concurrent use. And as stated earlier in my answer: *"The global functions are safe for concurrent use..."*

What you do call from multiple goroutines concurrently is `rand.Intn()`, but again, it's safe to do that.

Comment: Thank you for putting in more effort explaining the `Seed` method than the maintainers of this package.  They may value their own time more than that of the reader, but documentation is read more often than its written.